# tapply returns NA for every level of the factor index or insists the object and index are different lengths

Tags: r, date, dataframe, mean, tapply

I'm trying to use tapply to get the average weight of turtles caught per day. tapply returns NA for every date value (class:POSIXct) for every approach I've tried

I've tried: 
calling tapply on the weight column and date column -> arguments are different lengths error

removing records with NA values in the weight column of my dataframe then calling tapply on the weight column and date column. -> arguments are different lengths error

calling tapply on the na.omit call of the weight column and the date column indexed by the na.omit call of the weight column -> arguments are different lengths error

calling tapply on the na.omit call of the weight column and the factor-coerced date column indexed by the na.omit call of the weight column -> returns NA for every level of the factor-coerced date column

## head of original dataframe

```
> head(stinkpotData)
       Date     DateCt  Species Turtle.ID ID.Code             Location Recapture Weight.g C.Length.mm
1  6/1/2001 2001-06-01 Stinkpot         1       1   keck lab dock site         0      190          95
2  6/1/2001 2001-06-01 Stinkpot         2      10        Right of dock         0      200         100
3  8/9/2001 2001-08-09 Stinkpot         2      10 #4 Deep Right of lab         1      175         104
4 8/27/2001 2001-08-27 Stinkpot         2      10 #4 Deep Right of lab         1      175         105
5  6/1/2001 2001-06-01 Stinkpot         3      11        Right of dock         0      200         109
6 10/3/2001 2001-10-03 Stinkpot         3      11 #4 Deep Right of lab         1      205         109
  C.Width.mm Female.1.Male.2 Rotation                                  Marks
1         70            <NA>     <NA>                                   <NA>
2         72            <NA>     <NA>                                   <NA>
3         72               2     <NA>                                   Male
4         71               2     <NA>    male, 1 small leech Right front leg
5         74            <NA>     <NA>                          algae covered
6         76               2     <NA> male, 1 lg & 1 sm leech right rear leg
```

## head of the original dataframe with records with NA weights omitted (checked that NAs were actually omitted)

```
> head(noNAWeightsDf)
       Date     DateCt  Species Turtle.ID ID.Code             Location Recapture Weight.g C.Length.mm
1  6/1/2001 2001-06-01 Stinkpot         1       1   keck lab dock site         0      190          95
2  6/1/2001 2001-06-01 Stinkpot         2      10        Right of dock         0      200         100
3  8/9/2001 2001-08-09 Stinkpot         2      10 #4 Deep Right of lab         1      175         104
4 8/27/2001 2001-08-27 Stinkpot         2      10 #4 Deep Right of lab         1      175         105
5  6/1/2001 2001-06-01 Stinkpot         3      11        Right of dock         0      200         109
6 10/3/2001 2001-10-03 Stinkpot         3      11 #4 Deep Right of lab         1      205         109
  C.Width.mm Female.1.Male.2 Rotation                                  Marks
1         70            <NA>     <NA>                                   <NA>
2         72            <NA>     <NA>                                   <NA>
3         72               2     <NA>                                   Male
4         71               2     <NA>    male, 1 small leech Right front leg
5         74            <NA>     <NA>                          algae covered
6         76               2     <NA> male, 1 lg & 1 sm leech right rear leg
```

## calling tapply on the columns in the original dataframe

```
> tapply(stinkpotData$Weight.g, stinkpotData$DateCt, FUN = mean)
Error in tapply(stinkpotData$Weight.g, stinkpotData$DateCt, FUN = mean) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

## calling tapply on the columns in the noNA dataframe

```
>tapply(noNAWeightsDf$Weight.g, noNAWeightsDf$DateCt, FUN = mean)
Error in tapply(noNAWeightsDf$Weight.g, noNAWeightsDf$DateCt, FUN = mean) : 
  arguments must have same length
```

## calling tapply on the na.omit call of the weight column and the date column

```
> tapply(na.omit(stinkpotData$Weight.g), stinkpotData$DateCt[!is.na(stinkpotData$Weight.g)], FUN = mean)
Error in tapply(na.omit(stinkpotData$Weight.g), stinkpotData$DateCt[!is.na(stinkpotData$Weight.g)],  : 
  arguments must have same length
```

## calling tapply on the na.omit call of the weight column and the factor-

```
coerced date column indexed by the na.omit call of the weight column 
tapply(na.omit(stinkpotData$Weight.g), as.factor(stinkpotData$DateCt[!is.na(stinkpotData$Weight.g)]), FUN = mean)
2001-01-07 2001-06-01 2001-06-04 2001-06-06 2001-06-07 2001-06-11 2001-06-12 2001-06-15 2001-06-19 
        NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA 
2001-06-20 2001-06-25 2001-06-27 2001-06-29 2001-07-03 2001-07-09 2001-07-11 2001-07-13 2001-07-16 
        NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA ................etc

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

## calling warnings() after the above error gives:

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
.......................etc
```

EDIT:

`split(na.omit(stinkpotData$Weight.g), as.factor(stinkpotData$DateCt[!is.na(stinkpotData$Weight.g)]))`
Gave a list of the individual weights of turtles on each date. Verified that it was of mode list. Its elements were of mode numeric, class factor. lapply on the split list with FUN=mean still returned NA for each level of date. Can get means of individual elements of the split list of coerced to vectors but not quite what I need.

EDIT 2:
Finally got the result I wanted, but the steps to get there seem over-complicated and I still don't understand why using tapply won't work. I had to call split as in the first edit, then coerce each element of the resultant list to class numeric (originally returned as class factor) with lapply, then call mean on every element with lapply:

```
weightsDateList = split(na.omit(stinkpotData$Weight.g), as.factor(stinkpotData$DateCt[!is.na(stinkpotData$Weight.g)]))
weightsDateList = lapply(weightsDateList, FUN = as.numeric)
weightsDateList = lapply(weightsDateList, FUN = mean)
```

EDIT 3:
I realize now that the result I get from the solution in EDIT 2 and calling tapply( severely underestimates the means, so still lost.

EDIT 4: 
Realized that converting weight to class numeric returned the number of the level of the weight from when it was a factor, which explains the severe underestimation of means.

I want the tapply call to return every date with turtle weight(s) and its respective average weight of turtles caught on those dates. Thanks and I apologize if I'm missing something easy.

Comment: Have you tried `aggregate(Weight.g ~ DateCt, data = stinkpotData, mean)`

Comment: unless you have reason to, I'd recommend against using tapply. `data.table` and `dplyr` both offer much easier grouping facilities. I'm quite partial to data.table but I recommend checking out both & seeing what suits you

Comment: I don't see a problem with `tapply` but I'm quite partial to `base` R. Many of its methods offer grouping facilities: `tapply`, `by`, `split`, `ave`, `aggregate` to name a few. I recommend checking these out & seeing what suits you.

Comment: Please `dput` a few rows of your actual original dataframe that reproduces this error. Did you check NAs in `DateCt`?

Comment: @heds1 aggregate(Weight.g ~ DateCt, data = stinkpotData, mean) gave an invalid type error as DateCt is a list it seems. I coerced it to a factor then called aggregate but it just returned NA for every level again

Comment: @Parfait the original data frame has NA values for weight very infrequently, first one in the 65th or so record. Unfortunately away from WiFi so I can’t send code atm. There aren’t any NAs in the DateCt column though (double checked with sum(is.na()))

Comment: To reiterate, please post the `dput` of your original data frame with enough rows to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) your error. With what you posted, I cannot reproduce any error with `tapply`. See my attempt: https://rextester.com/NHS30844.

Comment: @Parfait https://rextester.com/VEZH73548

Comment: @Parfait the code here gives the errors I reference in the title when I put it into RStudio but gives different errors in rextester: https://rextester.com/edit/VEZH73548 I actually tried your solution of calling as.numeric on weight.g earlier but the resulting means aren't right (as with the split method procedure I tried in EDIT 2. The vast majority of weights are over 100 but the means returned with either the tapply or split calls way underestimate that

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to use `tapply` you must heed the following rules regarding its arguments:

- **First** argument must be or cast-able to a logical, integer, or numeric. Factors, characters, or other types cannot be used here.
- **Second** argument must be or cast-able to a factor which can be any basic data type with exceptions to more complex types. This includes multiple groupings if using `list()` where `tapply` then returns a matrix.

  - Because this argument only takes factors, it is redundant to cast with `as.factor()` which likely `tapply` does already under the hood.
- **Third** argument must be  a function that returns an atomic, numeric value for each input (i.e., first argument) sliced by group(s) (i.e., second argument).
- **Length:** The first and second argument must be the same length which is given if both derive from a data frame as data frames by definition is a `class` object of `list` type that contains equal length atomic vectors.

  - Because of this rule, avoid running *different* operations on first or second argument as it can result in *different* lengths. Instead, either run same operation on both vectors or even better run operation on the whole data frame before calling `tapply`:
  - Since each `NA` maintains a length of one (unlike `NULL`), its presence does not matter in `tapply`. However, the child function can have issues with `NA` that `tapply` raises upstream.

---

Specifically, your issue regards the original types: factor type of *Weight.g*, and `POSIXlt` type of *DateCt*. Consider converting these types to adhere to `tapply`.

But do not directly cast these original types to `factor` as its underlying numerics or factor level number will result causing undesirable results. For numeric conversion, cast first to `character`. For `POSIXlt` cast to `Date` or `character`. Below demonstrates with OP's `dput` of first ten rows with other grouping methods.

**Data** *(only two relevant columns)*

```
stinkpotDataDeparsed <- structure(list(Weight.g = structure(c(15L, 13L, 20L, 16L, 15L, 
12L, NA, 12L, 15L, 20L, 26L), .Label = c("100", "105", "106", 
"107", "110", "115", "1150", "120", "125", "126", "128", "130", 
"135", "138", "140", "145", "150", "155", "159", "160", "165", 
"168", "170", "175", "180", "185", "187", "190", "195", "20", 
"200", "205", "210", "215", "220", "225", "230", "235", "245", 
"250", "40", "45", "50", "55", "60", "65", "70", "75", "80", 
"85", "90", "95", "oops!"), class = "factor"), DateCt = structure(list(
    sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(20L, 30L, 8L, 29L, 
    23L, 26L, 12L, 17L, 29L, 13L, 4L), mon = c(8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L), year = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 
    102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 101L), wday = c(4L, 0L, 
    4L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L), yday = c(262L, 272L, 
    311L, 332L, 173L, 176L, 192L, 197L, 209L, 163L, 154L), isdst = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("EST", 
    "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", "EST", 
    "EST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
"zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = c("EST", 
"EST", "   "))), .Names = c("Weight.g", "DateCt"), row.names = 60:70, class = "data.frame")
```

**Cleaning**

```
# REMOVE NAs FROM DATA FRAME TO RUN ON ALL COLUMNS BUT DOES NOT MATTER W/ tapply
stinkpotDataDeparsed <- stinkpotDataDeparsed[!is.na(stinkpotDataDeparsed$Weight.g),]

# CAST FACTOR TYPE TO NUMERIC    
stinkpotDataDeparsed$Weight.g <- as.numeric(as.character(stinkpotDataDeparsed$Weight.g))

# CAST POISXlt TO DATE OR CHARACTER FOR FACTOR-ABILITY
stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt <- as.Date(stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt)
# stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt <- as.character(stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt)
```

**Tapply** *(returns a vector)*

```
with(stinkpotDataDeparsed, tapply(Weight.g, DateCt, mean))     

# 2001-06-04 2001-09-20 2001-09-30 2001-11-08 2001-11-29 2002-06-23 2002-06-26 2002-07-17 2002-07-29 2003-06-13 
#        185        140        135        160        145        140        130        130        140        160
```

**Aggregate** *(returns a data frame)*

```
aggregate(Weight.g ~ DateCt, data = stinkpotDataDeparsed, mean)

#        DateCt Weight.g
# 1  2001-06-04      185
# 2  2001-09-20      140
# 3  2001-09-30      135
# 4  2001-11-08      160
# 5  2001-11-29      145
# 6  2002-06-23      140
# 7  2002-06-26      130
# 8  2002-07-17      130
# 9  2002-07-29      140
# 10 2003-06-13      160
```

**Ave** *(returns vector of same length as input, so can be assigned a data frame column)*

```
stinkpotDataDeparsed$Wgt.Mean <- with(stinkpotDataDeparsed, ave(Weight.g, DateCt, FUN=mean))
stinkpotDataDeparsed

#    Weight.g     DateCt Wgt.Mean
# 60      140 2001-09-20      140
# 61      135 2001-09-30      135
# 62      160 2001-11-08      160
# 63      145 2001-11-29      145
# 64      140 2002-06-23      140
# 65      130 2002-06-26      130
# 67      130 2002-07-17      130
# 68      140 2002-07-29      140
# 69      160 2003-06-13      160
# 70      185 2001-06-04      185
```

**By** *(object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`, returns a list)*

```
by(stinkpotDataDeparsed, stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt, FUN=function(sub) mean(sub$Weight.g))

# stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt: 2001-06-04
# [1] 185
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt: 2001-09-20
# [1] 140
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt: 2001-09-30
# [1] 135
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt: 2001-11-08
# [1] 160
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt: 2001-11-29
# [1] 145
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt: 2002-06-23
# [1] 140
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt: 2002-06-26
# [1] 130
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt: 2002-07-17
# [1] 130
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt: 2002-07-29
# [1] 140
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# stinkpotDataDeparsed$DateCt: 2003-06-13
# [1] 160
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/PYL99792)